# What is the order of the task result when using WhenAll and ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Just want to know what is the order of the task result when using WhenAll and ContinueWith. 
Are these results gurenteed to be in the same order with task Id?

I wrote below code

```
public static async Task<string> PrintNumber(int number)
{
    return await Task.Delay(number*1000).ContinueWith(_=>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);return "TaskId:"+Task.CurrentId+" Result:"+number;
    });
}

public static void Main()
{

    Task.WhenAll(new[]
    {
        PrintNumber(3),
        PrintNumber(2),
        PrintNumber(1),

    }).ContinueWith((antecedent) => 
    { 
        foreach(var a in antecedent.Result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    });
}
```

and run that several times in linqpad getting the same result

```
1
2
3
TaskId:15 Result:3
TaskId:14 Result:2
TaskId:13 Result:1
```

or

```
1
2
3
TaskId:18 Result:3
TaskId:17 Result:2
TaskId:16 Result:1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With that specific invocation, the argument of a `Task[]` -- the order is **not** guaranteed.

In fact, according to the `Task.WhenAll(Task[])` documentation there is no mention of order whatsoever. But if you use the `Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>)` overload it reads as [follows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If none of the tasks faulted and none of the tasks were canceled, the resulting task will end in the RanToCompletion state. The Result of the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the results of the supplied tasks **in the same order as they were provided** (e.g. if the input tasks array contained t1, t2, t3, the output task's Result will return an TResult[] where arr[0] == t1.Result, arr1 == t2.Result, and arr[2] == t3.Result).

Comment: Thanks @David, just decompile the whenAll through the reshaper, whenAll(tasks[]) and WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks) should be same. AKA. The order of the result should be same as they were provided as well

Comment: It is close, but there are differences that could impact that guarantee. I based my answer on the documentation specifically.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `Task.WhenAll` (with either an enumerable or a params array), the order of the results match the order of the tasks passed to that method.

That is to say, this is true:

```
var task1 = PrintNumber(3);
var task2 = PrintNumber(2);
var task3 = PrintNumber(1);
var taskResults = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
// taskResults[0] is the same as task1.Result
// taskResults[1] is the same as task2.Result
// taskResults[2] is the same as task3.Result
```

However, `ContinueWith` is an entirely different story. `ContinueWith` attaches  a continuation, and this continuation will run sometime after the task completes.

In your particular code, you're *not* attaching a continuation to the task passed to `Task.WhenAll`. But if you were, then that continuation could run anytime after that task completed.

On a side note, [don't use `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) (as I explain on my blog). Just use `await` instead; the resulting code is more correct, cleaner, and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Cleary, think i understand your answer. Which is if I attach ContinueWith to task1,task2,task3, then there's no guarantee of the execution order of the code in ContinueWith.  Plus, I beleive  task1,task2,task3 should not follow the order of the tasks passed in as well

Comment: @ValidfroM: Right, if you attach a continuation to `task1`, then the `await Task.WhenAll` may complete before that continuation runs (or *while* it's running). However, the results of the `Task.WhenAll` task are in the order of the tasks passed to `Task.WhenAll`. The results will always be in the order 1,2,3; that's guaranteed. It doesn't matter if you attach continuations or not.